# How does PhoneSheriff block apps on non rooted Android device

Tags: android, process, blocking, kill

Actually, I am trying to implement an app on Android which can block other applications(as it is in **PhoneSheriff**)
I can get the functionality on rooted device just using linux *kill -9 pid*.
But there occur problems on non rooted device,in other words the methods provided by Android API such as
ActivityManager's  **killBackgroundProcess(String packageName)** do not make any effect.
I have got

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```